# Show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}}\geq 1-\frac{kx}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> Let $k>0$. Show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}}\geq 1-\frac{kx}{2}$$ for all $x>0$.

In order to prove the requested result I'm trying to prove that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}} -1+\frac{kx}{2}\geq0$$ for positive $x$. However, I'm stuck at proving the last inequality. Thank you in advance

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality#Generalization_of_exponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>\frac{2}{k}$, then
$$ 1-\frac{kx}2<0$$
and then the inequality holds automatically. For $x\in(0,\frac{2}{k}]$, by the LMVT for $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}}$ in $[0,x]$, there is $\xi\in(0,x)$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}}-1=-\frac{k}{2(\sqrt{1+k\xi})^3}(x-0)\ge -\frac{kx}{2} $$
and so
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}}\ge1-\frac{kx}{2}. $$
Here
$$ \frac{k}{2(\sqrt{1+k\xi})^3}\le \frac{k}{2} $$
is used.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $k$ and $x$ always appear as $kx$, so it suffices to prove the result
$$
g(y)\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}-1+y/2\geq0
$$
for $y>0$. To this end, check that $g'(y)>0$ for $y>0$ and $g(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $1+kx=u^2$ with $u\ge 1$ then we have to prove $$f(u)=3u-u^3\le 2$$ Can you show that $f(u)$ is decreasing for $u\ge 1$ ??

I leave it here

Comment: typo in third line

Comment: @person thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest proving that, given $ k>0 $, and $ x>0 $, we have : $$ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}}-1+\frac{kx}{2}=\frac{3k^{2}x^{2}}{4}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{1-y}{\left(1+kxy\right)^{2}\sqrt{1+kxy}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\end{array}$} $$

The result is then obvious.